# Elegant way to invert a map in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Learning Scala currently and needed to invert a Map to do some inverted value->key lookups.  I was looking for a simple way to do this, but came up with only:

```
(Map() ++ origMap.map(kvp=>(kvp._2->kvp._1)))
```

Anybody have a more elegant approach?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Assuming values are unique, this works:

```
(Map() ++ origMap.map(_.swap))
```

On Scala 2.8, however, it's easier:

```
origMap.map(_.swap)
```

Being able to do that is part of the reason why Scala 2.8 has a new collection library.

Comment: Careful! You can loose values with this solution. For example `Map(1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "B").map(_.swap)` results in `Map(A -> 1, B -> 3)`

Comment: @dev-null I'm sorry, but your example does not fall under the required assumption.

Comment: I agree. Sorry, I've overlooked that.

Answer (score 53):

Mathematically, the mapping might not be invertible (injective), e.g., from `Map[A,B]`, you can't get `Map[B,A]`, but rather you get `Map[B,Set[A]]`, because there might be different keys associated with same values. So, if you are interested in knowing all the keys, here's the code:

```
val m = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 4 -> "b")
m.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.keys)

res0: Map[String,Iterable[Int]] = Map(b -> Set(2, 4), a -> Set(1))
```

Starting scala 2.13, this becomes even simpler and more efficient:

```
m.groupMap(_._2)(_._1)
```

Comment: `.map(_._1)` would be more legibile as just `.keys`

Comment: Now thanks to you, even a few characters shorter. The difference now is that you get `Set`s instead of `List`s as before.

Comment: Be careful when using `.mapValues` because it returns a view. Occasionally, this is what you want, but if you aren't careful it can consume lots of memory and CPU. To force it into a map, you can do `m.groupBy(_._2).mapVaues(_.keys).map(identity)`, or you could replace the call to `.mapValues(_.keys)` with `.map { case (k, v) => k -> v.keys }`.

Comment: `.mapValues(_.keySet)` is a good option to get a Set rather than an Iterable

Comment: Using later versions of Scala, you can `m.groupMap(_._2)(_._1)`

Answer (score 9):

You can avoid the ._1 stuff while iterating in few ways.

Here's one way.  This uses a partial function that covers the one and only case that matters for the map:

```
Map() ++ (origMap map {case (k,v) => (v,k)})
```

Here's another way:

```
import Function.tupled        
Map() ++ (origMap map tupled {(k,v) => (v,k)})
```

The map iteration calls a function with a two element tuple, and the anonymous function wants two parameters.  Function.tupled makes the translation.

Answer (score 7):

OK, so this is a very old question with many good answers, but I've built the ultimate, be-all-and-end-all, Swiss-Army-knife, `Map` inverter and this is the place to post it.

It's actually two inverters. One for individual value elements...

```
//from Map[K,V] to Map[V,Set[K]], traverse the input only once
implicit class MapInverterA[K,V](m :Map[K,V]) {
  def invert :Map[V,Set[K]] =
    m.foldLeft(Map.empty[V, Set[K]]) {
      case (acc,(k, v)) => acc + (v -> (acc.getOrElse(v,Set()) + k))
    }
}
```

...and another, quite similar, for value collections.

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.mutable.Builder
import scala.language.higherKinds

//from Map[K,C[V]] to Map[V,C[K]], traverse the input only once
implicit class MapInverterB[K,V,C[_]](m :Map[K,C[V]]
                                     )(implicit ev :C[V] => TraversableOnce[V]) {
  def invert(implicit bf :CanBuildFrom[Nothing,K,C[K]]) :Map[V,C[K]] =
    m.foldLeft(Map.empty[V, Builder[K,C[K]]]) {
      case (acc, (k, vs)) =>
        vs.foldLeft(acc) {
          case (a, v) => a + (v -> (a.getOrElse(v,bf()) += k))
        }
    }.mapValues(_.result())
}
```

usage:

```
Map(2 -> Array('g','h'), 5 -> Array('g','y')).invert
//res0: Map(g -> Array(2, 5), h -> Array(2), y -> Array(5))

Map('q' -> 1.1F, 'b' -> 2.1F, 'c' -> 1.1F, 'g' -> 3F).invert
//res1: Map(1.1 -> Set(q, c), 2.1 -> Set(b), 3.0 -> Set(g))

Map(9 -> "this", 8 -> "that", 3 -> "thus", 2 -> "thus").invert
//res2: Map(this -> Set(9), that -> Set(8), thus -> Set(3, 2))

Map(1L -> Iterator(3,2), 5L -> Iterator(7,8,3)).invert
//res3: Map(3 -> Iterator(1, 5), 2 -> Iterator(1), 7 -> Iterator(5), 8 -> Iterator(5))

Map.empty[Unit,Boolean].invert
//res4: Map[Boolean,Set[Unit]] = Map()
```

I would prefer to have both methods in the same implicit class but the more time I spent looking into it the more problematic it appeared.

Answer (score 5):

I came here looking for a way to invert a Map of type Map[A, Seq[B]] to Map[B, Seq[A]], where each B in the new map is associated with every A in the old map for which the B was contained in A's associated sequence.

E.g.,
`Map(1 -> Seq("a", "b"), 2-> Seq("b", "c"))`
would invert to 
`Map("a" -> Seq(1), "b" -> Seq(1, 2), "c" -> Seq(2))`

Here's my solution :

```
val newMap = oldMap.foldLeft(Map[B, Seq[A]]().withDefaultValue(Seq())) {
  case (m, (a, bs)) => bs.foldLeft(m)((map, b) => map.updated(b, m(b) :+ a))
}
```

where oldMap is of type `Map[A, Seq[B]]` and newMap is of type `Map[B, Seq[A]]`

The nested foldLefts make me cringe a little bit, but this is the most straightforward way I could find to accomplish this type of inversion. Anyone have a cleaner solution?

Comment: very nice solution!
@Rok, his solution is somehow different than yours a bit I think because he transforms: `Map[A, Seq[B]]` to `Map[B, Seq[A]]` where your solution trasnforms `Map[A, Seq[B]]` to `Map[Seq[B], Seq[A]]`.

Comment: In that case, without two nested folds and possible more performant: `a.toSeq.flatMap { case (a, b) => b.map(_ -> a) }.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._1))`

Answer (score 2):

You could invert a map using:

```
val i = origMap.map({case(k, v) => v -> k})
```

The problem with this approach is that if your values, which have now become the hash keys in your map, are not unique you will drop the duplicate values. To illustrate:

```
scala> val m = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 1)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 1)

// Notice that 1 -> a is not in our inverted map
scala> val i = m.map({ case(k , v) => v -> k})
i: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> d, 2 -> b, 3 -> c)
```

To avoid this you can convert your map to a list of tuples first, then invert, so that you don't drop any duplicate values:

```
scala> val i = m.toList.map({ case(k , v) => v -> k})
i: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,a), (2,b), (3,c), (1,d))
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, in order to swap key/values without loosing keys associated to same values, we can use `Map`s new [groupMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#groupMap[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,CC[B]]) method, which (as its name suggests) is an equivalent of a `groupBy` and a `map`ping over grouped items.

```
Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 4 -> "b").groupMap(_._2)(_._1)
// Map("b" -> List(2, 4), "a" -> List(1))
```

This:

- `group`s elements based on their second tuple part (`_._2`) (group part of **group**Map)
- `map`s grouped items by taking their first tuple part (`_._1`) (map part of group**Map**)

This can be seen as a [one-pass version](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L578) of `map.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._1))`.

Comment: Too bad it won't transform `Map[K, C[V]]` into `Map[V, C[K]]`.

Answer (score 1):

In scala REPL:

```
scala> val m = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two)

scala> val reversedM = m map { case (k, v) => (v, k) }
reversedM: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(one -> 1, two -> 2)
```

Note that duplicate values will be overwritten by the last addition to the map:

```
scala> val m = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two", 3 -> "one")
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two, 3 -> one)

scala> val reversedM = m map { case (k, v) => (v, k) }
reversedM: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(one -> 3, two -> 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Inverse is a better name for this operation than reverse (as in "inverse of a mathematical function")
2. I often do this inverse transformation not only on maps but on other (including Seq) collections. I find it best not to limit the definition of my inverse operation to one-to-one maps. Here's the definition I operate with for maps (please suggest improvements to my implementation).

   ```
   def invertMap[A,B]( m: Map[A,B] ) : Map[B,List[A]] = {
     val k = ( ( m values ) toList ) distinct
     val v = k map { e => ( ( m keys ) toList ) filter { x => m(x) == e } }
     ( k zip v ) toMap
   }
   ```

If it's a one-to-one map, you end up with singleton lists which can be trivially tested and transformed to a Map[B,A] rather than Map[B,List[A]].

Answer (score 0):

We can try using this `foldLeft` function that will take care of collisions and invert the map in single traversal.

```
scala> def invertMap[A, B](inputMap: Map[A, B]): Map[B, List[A]] = {
     |     inputMap.foldLeft(Map[B, List[A]]()) {
     |       case (mapAccumulator, (value, key)) =>
     |         if (mapAccumulator.contains(key)) {
     |           mapAccumulator.updated(key, mapAccumulator(key) :+ value)
     |         } else {
     |           mapAccumulator.updated(key, List(value))
     |         }
     |     }
     |   }
invertMap: [A, B](inputMap: Map[A,B])Map[B,List[A]]

scala> val map = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 5)
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(5 -> 5, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 3)

scala> invertMap(map)
res0: Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(5 -> List(5), 2 -> List(1, 2), 3 -> List(3, 4))

scala> val map = Map("A" -> "A", "B" -> "A", "C" -> "C", "D" -> "C", "E" -> "E")
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(E -> E, A -> A, B -> A, C -> C, D -> C)

scala> invertMap(map)
res1: Map[String,List[String]] = Map(E -> List(E), A -> List(A, B), C -> List(C, D))
```