# Aggregate/Reduce by key function for a map in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, hashmap

I have a map as given below in scala.

```
Map("x"-> "abc", "y"->"adc","z"->"abc", "l"-> "ert","h"->"dfg", "p"-> "adc")
```

I want the output as follows:

```
Map("abc"->["x","z"],"adc"->["y" , "p"], "ert"->"l", "dfg"->"h")
```

So, the output has the array as the value of those those keys which had same values in inital map. How can I get that done optimally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegant way to invert a map in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338282/elegant-way-to-invert-a-map-in-scala)

Comment: `"l"` and `"h"` in the result should probably read `["l"]` and `["h"]`, right? Then Brian's answer from below is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `groupBy` followed by some manipulation of the values it outputs should do.

```
scala> m.groupBy(x => x._2).mapValues(_.keys.toList)
res10: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]]
  = Map(abc -> List(x, z), dfg -> List(h), ert -> List(l), adc -> List(y, p))
```